# PDF to Image Conversion not working in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Hello anyone please help me out,
In Cakephp i have the requirement of converting the dynamically generated pdf into .png image

So for this I did this :

```
               $a = explode('/',$pdfURL1);
            $b = $a[10];
            $c = explode('.',$b);
            $pdfname= $c[0];
            //pr($pdfname);
            //$dirname = "D:/Images/ExtractFromFTP/" . $pdfname;
            $dirname = BASE_URL."app/webroot/images/uploaded_files/research/" . $pdfname;
            pr($dirname);

            if (mkdir($dirname,0777)) {
            exec("convert -scale  1500x1000 " . escapeshellarg(BASE_URL."app/webroot/images/uploaded_files/research/${dirname}/img%d_".$pdfname.".png"));
            } else {
             echo 'Could not create dir!';
            }
```

The directory name **$dirname** and **$pdfname** is coming fine but **'Could not create dir!'** is echoed,and **.png** is not formed and saved in folder **app/webroot/images/uploaded_files/research/**

I am not sure,what's wrong I am doing,someone please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong constant to determine path of image, the code should be this

```
$dirname = WWW_ROOT."images".DS."uploaded_files".DS."research".DS. $pdfname;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot some file is created but not the .png image

Comment: @ Loken Makwana : Thanks for your help but still i am not getting it I think so something wrong is here :      exec("convert -scale  1500x1000 " . escapeshellarg(BASE_URL."app/webroot/images/uploaded_files/research/${dirname}/img%d_".$pdfname.".png")); i need to change path inside exec() ???